# Getting Steps details with respect to fitness activities?

Tags: android, google-fit, google-health

I am working with Google Fit SDK, I can easily fetch steps details but I am really struggling with getting which activity was being done while taking those steps.

```
DataSource ESTIMATED_STEP_DELTAS = new DataSource.Builder()
            .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .setType(DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED)
            .setStreamName("estimated_steps")
            .setAppPackageName("com.google.android.gms")
            .build();
    DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .aggregate(ESTIMATED_STEP_DELTAS, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();
```

In response, If i check DataSet source its always **com.google.step_count.delta**.

[image: I want something like this]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [bucketByActivityType](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/request/DataReadRequest.Builder.html#bucketByActivityType) instead of bucketByTime.

Then, on the dataset of the resulting Bucket, use [getActivity()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/Bucket.html#getActivity()) to get the activity type.